# sql 3 tables sum

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables, `bookings`, `companies` and `flights`. `bookings` has `no_seats` and`seat_price`. I need to calculate sum of `no_seats` * `seat_price` for each company (for all their `flights` together). `flight` has `company_id` and `booking` has `flight_id`. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: It helps if you could provide some DDL for the specific scenario so we can reproduce it, plus the query you currently have. Let us know where you specifically got stuck so we can help you with the specific problem you have (as opposed to having to write out the entire query ourselves).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "companies" has a 1-to-many relation with "flights" and "flights" have 1-to-many relation with "bookings":

```
select c.CompanyName, sum(b.no_seats * b.seat_price) as total
from Companies c
inner join Flights f on f.Company_Id = c.Company_id
inner join Bookings b on b.Flight_ID = f.Flight_ID
group by c.Company_ID, c.CompanyName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't provide enough informations, but I guess this is what you want ?

```
Select C.Company_Id, SUM( B.no_seats * B.seat_price) as [Desired Calculation]
From Company C, Flights F, Bookings B
    Where C.Company_Id = F.Company_Id
    And   F.Flight_Id = B.Flight_Id
Group By C.Company_Id
```

If there are any further questions please feel free to ask.